# problem default meta description

Tags: magento-2.1

on my magento 2.4.1 I have a problem with html header
in meta description, I have words with spelling mistakes, I cannot correct them, when saving impossible, plus it goes into blocking mode

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to this?
[image: give me more information]

After u write your meta description u need to do a cache,check at what level you are editing it, maybe is wrong level.